# class / struct member Alignment, Data Packing under 64bits program

Tags: c++, c++17

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(B) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(Based on 64bits program), I notice the differences of the values under Visual Studio and gcc, respectively are 24 and 16.
[image]
[image]

By analyzing, the virtual table costs 8 bytes, int a and int b respectively is 4 bytes. So the alignment for VS is 8 but for gcc is 4.

What does cause the difference, how does the C++ standard say?

```
struct C {
    char a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, under VS, the size of this struct is 12 that implies the alignment is 4, different from the alignment for class B under VS.
[image]

Why?

Comment: Basically nothing is spelled out in the standard about this.  How virtual functions are implemented and how big classes are, are all implementation defined.

Comment: Looks like MSVC is adding 4 padding bytes at the end of the class data. This is acceptable by the Standard but not required by it. The reason compilers differ in whether they add this end-packing will likely be related to how/where the virtual tables are stored.

Comment: You can use [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) for the compiler to tell you the alignment, rather than inferring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that `alignof(A) == 8 && sizeof(A) == 16` on both compilers, laid out as 8 bytes for a pointer, 4 bytes for `int A::a`, and 4 bytes of padding.

Since `A` is a base class, it is a potentially overlapping subobject of any `B` objects. This means that the padding can be reused.

gcc/clang (More specifically, things that follow the [Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types)) have to allocate `int B::b` into the 4 bytes of padding in the base class, so `sizeof(B)` is also 16 (but `alignof(B) == 8` still).

MSVC (and clang compiling for Windows) follow a different ABI, which happens to not reuse the tail padding, so the layout of B looks like 8 bytes for a pointer, 4 bytes for `int A::a`, 4 bytes of padding (inherited from `A`), 4 bytes for `int B::b`, and 4 more bytes of padding.

---

As for your last questions, typically vtables are implemented as a pointer stored at the front of each object. This pointer will usually have the size an alignment requirement of 8 on a 64 bit platform. `C` would be comparable if it looked like:

```cpp
struct C {
    void* p;
    char a;
    // 3 bytes padding
    int b;
    char c;
    // 7 bytes padding to alignment of 8
};

static_assert(sizeof(C) == 24 && alignof(C) == 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the other's help, I finally figure it out.

alignof(B) under VS and GCC are same which is 8.

**1. Why sizeof(B) are different?**

Because they store the virtual function pointer (vptr) at different places, for VS at beginning and for GCC at the end. Something like this,

//B for VS

```
class B{
class A{
void* vptr;
int a;
};
int b;};
//B for GCC
class B{
int a;
int b;
void* vptr;
};
```

For VS, sizeof(B) = sizeof(vptr) + (sizeof(int a) padding to 8) + (sizeof(int b) padding to 8) = 24.

For GCC, sizeof(B)  = (sizeof(int a)+sizeof(int b) padding to 8) + sizeof(vptr) = 16.

**2. Why alignof(C) is 4?**

Because there is virtual function in struct C. If you add `virutal ~C(){}` for C, alignof(C) would be 8 either.